# Download file from URL to a string

Tags: c#

How could I use C# to download the contents of a URL, and store the text in a string, without having to save the file to the hard drive?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
string contents;
using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
    contents = wc.DownloadString(url);
```

Comment: As noted by @CaffGeek you will want to dispose of the `WebClient` in a `using` block.

Comment: This is now Obsolete. When compiling VS gives this warning: `WebRequest, HttpWebRequest, ServicePoint, and WebClient are obsolete. Use HttpClient instead.` It works great though.

Answer (score 16):

Use a WebClient

```
var result = string.Empty;
using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    result = webClient.DownloadString("http://some.url");
}
```

Comment: One minute too late!

Answer (score 5):

See [WebClient.DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring.aspx). Note there is also a [WebClient.DownloadStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringasync.aspx) method, if you need to do this without blocking the calling thread.

Answer (score 4):

For more simpler and none-obsolete solution:

```
    public static string Download(string url)
    {
        using var client = new HttpClient();
        var content = client.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
        return content;
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `Result` like that. It **not only synchronously waits (thus blocks UI) but also has a potential to cause a deadlock**. Don't call asynchronous methods synchronously. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76582825/2638227) shows the correct usage.

Answer (score 3):

use this Code Simply

```
var r= string.Empty;
using (var web = new System.Net.WebClient())
       r= web.DownloadString("http://TEST.COM");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

WebClient client = new WebClient();

string dnlad = client.DownloadString("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");

File.WriteAllText(@"c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Data1.txt", dnlad);
```

got it from MVA 
hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

None Obsolete solution:

async:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
using HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
using HttpContent content = response.Content;
var r = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

sync:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
using HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
using HttpContent content = response.Content;
var r = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: In your sync example I think you want `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, it will give you the true exception rather than an aggregate exception.

Comment: Tono's sync example will work in both .NET Framework 4.8 and .NET 6 if the using statements are replaced with the older using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result)) { .. } style.

Comment: Why not use `GetStringAsync(url).Result` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Starting in .NET 6, the `WebRequest`, `WebClient` and `ServicePoint` classes are [obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/networking/6.0/webrequest-deprecated?source=recommendations). Use the [System.Net.Http.HttpClient class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) instead. (Actually using `HttpClient` class as HTTP API is the *preferred way* for .NET Framework 4.5 onward.)

Use the following method to get string content of a URL:

```
public async Task<string> DownloadString(string url)
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    string content = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
    return content;
}
```

To call:

```
string content = await DownloadString("https://stackoverflow.com");
```

For the sake of simplicity, the `DownloadString()` method creates the `HttpClient` instance on every call. But the
[recommended way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75953415/2638227) is to create it via `IHttpClientFactory` interface.