# How to get content from file from this URL?

Tags: c#, url

I have this URL: [URL from Google](https://www.google.com.vn/s?hl=vi&gs_nf=1&tok=i-GIkt7KnVMbpwUBAkCCdA&cp=5&gs_id=n&xhr=t&q=thanh&pf=p&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=be3c25b6da637b79&biw=1366&bih=362&tch=1&ech=5&psi=8_pDUNWHFsbYrQeF5IDIDg.1346632409892.1)

When open link in new tab, the browser force me download it. After download, I get a text file named "s". But I want use C#  access to this URL and get it's text, don't save it as a file to computer. Is any way to do this?

Comment: do you want to do this via C# code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download a file from a URL in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307688/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-in-c) or [Download file from URL to a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231969/download-file-from-url-to-a-string).

Comment: download, read, and delete the file.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(@"http://yourUrl");

using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse())
using(var content = response.GetResponseStream())
using(var reader = new StreamReader(content)){
    var strContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

This will place the contents of the request into strContent.

Or as [adrianbanks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116923/adrianbanks) mentioned below simply use [WebClient.DownloadString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx)

Comment: What's wrong with using [`WebClient.DownloadString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring.aspx), which can do the same in a single line of code?

Comment: Nothing... I guess I am just so used to using WebRequest because I am hardly ever just getting a single resource, or have to deal with headers. To be honest it didn't even pop into my head until you mentioned it just now.

Comment: @adrianbanks - for one, I don't believe it works in a PCL.

Answer (score 56):

Try this:

```
var url = "https://www.google.com.vn/s?hl=vi&gs_nf=1&tok=i-GIkt7KnVMbpwUBAkCCdA&cp=5&gs_id=n&xhr=t&q=thanh&pf=p&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=be3c25b6da637b79&biw=1366&bih=362&tch=1&ech=5&psi=8_pDUNWHFsbYrQeF5IDIDg.1346632409892.1";

var textFromFile = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(url);
```

Edit, 2022 Update (`using System.Net.Http;`):

```
var result = await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync("https://example.com/test.txt");
```

Comment: Don't like the idea of not cleaning up the `WebClient` object. Always like to use those in using blocks.

Answer (score 17):

Since this question and my previous answer is fairly old now, a more modern answer would be to use `HttpClient` from `System.Net.Http`

```
using System.Net.Http;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        async static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            string result = await client.GetStringAsync("https://example.com/test.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

If not within an async function, then:

```
string result = client.GetStringAsync("https://example.com/test.txt").Result;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, because other methods are obsoleted.

Answer (score 3):

For asp.net core / .Net 5+, you should inject HttpClient in your service. You should not manually create a new instance.

```
public class MyService {
   private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
   public MyService(HttpClient httpClient) {
       _httpClient = httpClient;
   }
   
   public async Task Foo() {
       var myString = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://my-url/file.txt");
   }
}
```

Injecting HttpClient will use IHttpClientFactory behind the scenes. Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests