# Substitute File.Readlines() with something that is able to read URL/https

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to parse a .csv file located in Azure blob storage. When I parse the .csv file from my local using `File.Readlines()`, it works fine. When I pass the path of the blob and debug, I get the following message at `File.Readlines()`:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
public IList<blabla> getFiles()
        {
            _rootFileDirectory = configurationService.GetString("stuff-stuff-stuff-stuff");

            var path = Path.Combine(_rootFileDirectory + "File", $"{_Id}.csv");
            var filePath = path.Contains("https://") ? path.Replace('\\', '/') : path;
            var listOfObjects = Parser(filePath); <-----
            return listOfObjects;
        }

        private IList<blabla> Parser(string filePath)
        {
            var Data = File.ReadLines(filePath); <-----
            foreach...
        }
```

The path that keeps failing is:

```
<add key="stuff-stuff-stuff-stuff" value="https://*******.blob.core.windows.net/******/" />
```

Again, when I run from my local (`C:\Users\*******\Desktop\`), it works fine. I'm guessing this is because `File.Readlines()` isn't able to read https paths. Can anyone confirm this and help me find a work-around with the same functionality?

Thanks in advance for helping a noob out.

Comment: Maybe this would answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240857/how-to-get-content-from-file-from-this-url

Comment: Don't get distracted by the incorrect comment above, you will want to use the .NET SDK for Azure Storage. [See this for a walkthrough](https://medium.com/@rammonzito/azure-blob-storage-using-a-net-core-console-application-106a0c2e6de5) of using a `BlobClient` to download a blob.

Comment: Is it useful for you? If it is helpful, could you please accept the solution as an answer? it may help more people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read csv file stored in Azure blob, you need to download it from Azure blob storage at first then you can read its content. For more details, please refer to [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5251396/Use-Azure-Functions-to-process-a-CSV-File-and-impo) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet)

For example

1. Install sdk

```
dotnet add package Azure.Storage.Blobs
```

2. Code

```
            string accountName = "";
            string accountKey = "";
            string blobUri = "";
            StorageSharedKeyCredential keyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
            BlobClient blob = new BlobClient(new Uri(blobUri), keyCredential);
            BlobDownloadInfo downloadInfo = await blob.DownloadAsync();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(downloadInfo.Content)) {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var columnName = line.Split(',');
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {

                    string splits = reader.ReadLine();
                    var rowValue = splits.Split(',');

                    // process the value as your need
                }

            }
```