# C# Reading XML from url while using XMLSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core

I have been reading [How To Parse XML In .NET Core](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/04/23/how-to-parse-xml-in-net-core/) There they show an example on parsing XML using XMLSerializer.

```
[XmlRoot("MyDocument", Namespace = "http://www.dotnetcoretutorials.com/namespace")]
public class MyDocument
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    public MyAttributeProperty MyAttributeProperty { get; set; }

    [XmlArray]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "MyListItem")]
    public List MyList { get; set; }
}

public class MyAttributeProperty
{
    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

and to read it:

```
using (var fileStream = File.Open("test.xml", FileMode.Open))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyDocument));
    var myDocument = (MyDocument)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);

    Console.WriteLine($"My Property : {myDocument.MyProperty}");
    Console.WriteLine($"My Attribute : {myDocument.MyAttributeProperty.Value}");

    foreach(var item in myDocument.MyList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

In the code above itreads the local xml file:

`using (var fileStream = File.Open("test.xml", FileMode.Open))`.

I want to read an XML file from URL, and make use of XmlSerializer, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: Hello there. Can you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240857/how-to-get-content-from-file-from-this-url  Maybe it will be usefull

Comment: Also this one about StreamReader: https://www.luisquintanilla.me/2017/12/18/read-file-from-url-dotnet-core/

Comment: A bit of terminology: *parsing* XML is the process of turning lexical XML (with angle brackets) into a tree representation. *Serialization* is the reverse process, turning the tree representation into lexical XML with angle brackets. So the idea of "parsing using a serializer" doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have your XML parsing logic in place, all you need is to swap out the file reading for an HTTP request.

```cs
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var content = await client.GetStreamAsync("http://...");

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyDocument));
    var myDocument = (MyDocument)serializer.Deserialize(new MemoryStream(content));

    Console.WriteLine($"My Property : {myDocument.MyProperty}");
    Console.WriteLine($"My Attribute : {myDocument.MyAttributeProperty.Value}");

    foreach(var item in myDocument.MyList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: `var myDocument = (MyDocument)serializer.Deserialize(content);` says: `Cannot resolve method 'Deserialize(string)', candidates are: object Deserialize(System.IO.Stream) (in class XmlSerializer) object Deserialize(System.IO.TextReader) (in class XmlSerializer) object Deserialize(System.Xml.XmlReader) (in class XmlSerializer`

Comment: `client.GetStreamAsync(url)` works tho. Update the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I see. I haven't testing it, but all you need to do is turn your content (string) into a Stream.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: Just nitpicking. There is a missing ) after `new MemoryStream(content)`. I can't edit only one char.