# Displaying a txt file accessed via http with a winforms application

Tags: c#

I am trying to display the contents of a text file hosted on a server within a richtextbox but am having an error stating URI formats are not supported.

If I access the txt file from my local drive I can do the following:

```
public void ReadFile() {

TextReader reader = File.OpenText(@"help.txt");
richtextBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();        
}
```

How can i have the same outcome with a remote file?

The txt file is accessed via http. the Url for example is:

`Http://www.example.com/help.txt`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download file from URL to a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231969/download-file-from-url-to-a-string)

Comment: you might use `HttpClient`

Comment: Amit, I have no experience of httpclient, could you elaborate please?

Comment: You don't need experience, you need google and webclient. Click the duplicate. string contents;
using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
    contents = wc.DownloadString(url);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
string url_data = wc.DownloadString("http://example.com/1.txt");
richtextBox1.Text = url_data;
```

Hope this helps.