# VBA download file to a string variable

Tags: string, vba, excel, curl

How to download a file from URL to a string variable without saving it to local drive? Similarly to this method in C# I would like it in VBA: [Download file from URL to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3231969/1903793)

Here is something with download file to disc space: [How do i download a file using VBA (Without internet explorer)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17877389/1903793) While it can be some hint, I would like to avoid this intermediate step of getting the file to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `WinHttpRequest` class you can achieve the file, the .Open method need 2 args: the request method "GET"/"POST", the URL string.
The third arg is optional, boolean, default is True for asynchronous mode:

```
Set httpRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
URL = "http://urlo_of_the_file_you_want"
httpRequest.Open "GET", URL, False
httpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
httpRequest.Send
httpRequest.WaitForResponse
Debug.Print httpRequest.Status
Debug.Print httpRequest.ResponseText
mystring = httpRequest.ResponseText
```

Then you get the file in the var name `mystring`

Comment: This works great, except it seems you forgot the:

`code`httpRequest.Send`code`

Before the WaitForResponse

Answer (score 0):

```
Set httpRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
URL = "http://urlo_of_the_file_you_want"
httpRequest.Open "GET", URL, False
httpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
httpRequest.send
httpRequest.WaitForResponse
Debug.Print httpRequest.Status
Debug.Print httpRequest.ResponseText
mystring = httpRequest.ResponseText
```

Have to add `httpRequest.send` before `httpRequest.WaitForResponse`