# HTTP Request to get HTML code in C#

Tags: c#

I want to get the HTML code from http://www.w3schools.com/
Here is my code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient("www.w3schools.com", 80);
        client.SendTimeout = 3000;
        client.ReceiveTimeout = 3000;
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
        writer.WriteLine("GET www.w3schools.com HTTP/1.1");
        writer.WriteLine("Host: www.w3schools.com");
        writer.WriteLine();
        writer.Flush();

        string response = reader.ReadToEnd();

        Console.WriteLine("Got Response: {0}", response);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

But I get the following: [image: The issue]
Where I'm wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231969/download-file-from-url-to-a-string

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you are attempting this using `TcpClient` rather than `HttpClient` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download file from URL to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231969/download-file-from-url-to-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For this TcpClient to work you need to have a Wporking TcpServer.
2. The correct uri should be like ("https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp") where after .com the file name will b provided.

The below code will work even without TcpServer.

```
public static void getSavedHtmlCode()
    {
        string html = string.Empty;


        try
        {
            var request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format("{0}", "https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp"));
            request.Method = "GET";
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            //prepare as html
            //html = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

            // Get the stream associated with the response.
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            // Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

            //prepare as html
            html = readStream.ReadToEnd();

            Console.WriteLine("Response stream received.");
            Console.WriteLine(html);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The second element of the GET line should be the query path, not the domain name. This should work:

```
writer.WriteLine("GET / HTTP/1.1");
writer.WriteLine("Host: www.w3schools.com");
```