# HttpClient - Get data without async

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, .net-4.5, dotnet-httpclient

I have `HttpClient` code which is supposed to download a PDF/Word document from given URL (SSRS report) and convert it to a memory stream but that is not working for all cases.

Sample URL:

```
http://server/ReportServer_SQL1?/Team/Report&rs:Command=Render&user=employeename&Liability=Current&Role1=MGA&rs:Command=Render&rc:Parameters=Collapsed&rs:Format=image
```

Error:

> System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
> at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
> at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsState.RetrieveBytes(Int32& bytesRetrieved)
> at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream, CompletionDelegate completionDelegate, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
> at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
> at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(Uri address)

Code

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encPassword);
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;

    // Error happens on this line
    var result = client.GetAsync(url).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); 

    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseContent = result.Content;
        var result_data = responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        ms = (MemoryStream)result_data;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Authentication issue");
    }
}
```

Comment: could you provide full error? with stack traces (if not sensitive)

Comment: Why are you so desparate to not use `async`? Side note: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol...` why do you have this? Just rely on the operating system to do the TLS protocol. Also `ms = (MemoryStream)result_data;` you can't do this as it might not be a `MemoryStream`, equally I don't why you would ever need to do so.

Comment: Why don't you make this method `async`? Downloading a file should be an asynchronous operation in general.

Comment: Also note that the recommended way is to create `HttpClient` objects using the `IHttpClientFactory` interface. Please have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75953233/c-sharp-httpclient-and-api/75953415#75953415).

Comment: @Charlieface This is a legacy code developed in .NET 4.5 framework. This code is just a part of a big functionality which is accessed in all over the legacy application. If I where to change the code to async the amount of changes I need to do the reference code will increase and regression test the whole application.

Comment: Did you refactor to `HttpClient` from something else? If so: why?

Comment: @Fildor I refactored the code to HttpClient from WebClient because I need to pass on Authorization token in request header.

Comment: So what is the full error message, and why do you need a `memoryStream` as opposed to just a `Stream`?

Comment: The error happens at this line var result = client.GetAsync(url).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); Error - Error while copying content to a stream. I am working on to get the full error.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.headers?view=netframework-4.5 .Net Framework 4.5 WebClient supports Headers?

Comment: @Fildor I tried the same earlier and it was not working that is why I move towards HttpClient. This above code in the question is working 50-50. The failure case may be because of size the file it tries to download.